# ios setting AppleLanguages and submission to app store

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

I am looking to set the language of the app other than the one from the iphone settings and I was browsing through a comment that said apple might not accept the app if I do that... can someone please confirm this !

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"en-US"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

no your application will not be rejected .. i see applications on apple store that you can change the language inside the application .. apple prefer not to do that but i don't think they will reject your app .. good luck.